# How to notice usergenerated event for zooming in Openlayers

Tags: javascript, dictionary, openlayers-3

I am coding a map with different vector sources, layers and cluster layers. The map is "bind" to a search-request in background.

I registered the event `zoomend` to get notified when the map is zoomed or panned. I noticed that the event has no `originalEvent` set and the functions `map.getEventPixel(evt)` are also not working. The main problem is that the event is triggered also when the extent is changing when setting new extent or even at init when loading the vectorlayer:

```
map.on('moveend', function(evt) {
    //ignore if on progress
    if (this.inProgress) {
       console.log('Map is in progress');
       return;
    }
}
```

How I can recognize whether the event is triggered by my code or by the user?

Comment: What kinds of interactions are triggered from the code panning only?

Comment: I registered no interactions of ol3. The event is triggered by zooming and panning (and  incorrectly also when setting a new extent and initiating the map)